# JavaScript Classes: Accessing method from within an Object's function property

Tags: javascript, class, methods, jsobject

I was wondering if it was possible if anyone knew a solution to the problem I am having. Let's say we have the following JavaScript class:

```
class foo {

    // Class Method.
    makeNoise() {
        console.log("bar");
    }

    // Class Object
    classObject = {
        makeASound: function() {
            makeNoise();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I were to call:

```
var foo = new foo();
foo.classObject.makeASound();
```

I would get an error, saying that makeNoise is not defined. Using 'this.' would not work because in this context it would look for a function inside classObject, and so would throw a 'is not a function' error. Is there anyway at all to able to access makeNoise from within an object's function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#:%7E:text=An%20arrow%20function%20expression%20is,cannot%20be%20used%20as%20constructors.) in order to avoid creating a new  context and then use the keyword [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in order to access the `makeNoise` method of the class correctly

```
class Foo {
  makeNoise() {
    console.log("bar");
  }
  classObject = {
    makeASound: () => { // arrow function for lexical scope
      this.makeNoise(); // using `this` to refer to the Foo method
    },
  };
}
```

You could also use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) if preferred

Answer (score -1):

Try `this.makeNoise()`

```
classObject = {
    makeASound: () => {
        this.makeNoise();
    }
}
```

Update: If we use an arrow function for `makeASound`, we can retain our `this` binding to the parent class. GMaiolo got this right in his answer.

Comment: This has the same error, because `function` creates a new `this`